# Does "chrome.storage.sync" store data in the cloud?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the chrome extensions docs, on [this page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) about local storage options, it says:

> To store user data for your extension, you can use either storage.sync
>   or storage.local. When using storage.sync, the stored data will
>   automatically be synced to any Chrome browser that the user is logged
>   into, provided the user has sync enabled.

I am confused about what "any Chrome browser that the user is logged into" means.  If I'm at home and use an extension which stores some data using `storage.sync`, and then turn off my computer and go to work and use another computer with the same extension installed, will the data from my home computer be available?  If so, what do I have to be logged into?  My google account?  And where is this data being stored?  On my Google drive?  If not, in what sense *is* the data synced?

Comment: yeah it looks like it saves it to the cloud, although I agree it's a little vague

Comment: I wonder where it stores the data if you *aren't* logged into a Google Account...I guess just locally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be logged into your google account in chrome. It is the first option on the settings page. The data is saved to your google account just like your settings and such are. See the official docs about it [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139)

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Out of curiosity, do you know if firefox provides a similar feature and, if so, where do they store the info for syncing in the cloud?

Comment: @Jonah Sorry, can't help you out with that, I don't use Firefox.

Comment: I wonder where it stores the data if you aren't logged into a Google Account...I guess just locally